# Theory of graphs, least possible number of edges with k-components.

Tags: graph-theory

I am just preparing for my exams from discrete mathematics, and really dont know how to proove that the least possible number of edges of graph with n vertices and k components is n-k.
Can anybody help me please? :-) thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a connected graph with the least number of edges is a tree. So a graph on $n$ vertices and $k$ component with the least number of edges is made up of $k$ trees. From this, you figure out the number of edges in the graph.

Comment: ah, thank you very much :) now i get it!